# Easy way to detect where ui thread is stalling on Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have taken over an Android project from a past employee and am wondering if there is an easy tool to use for profiling an Android application. I have a LinearLayout with a ProgressBar spinner inside of it. Now I am running a network call on a different thread while that spinner is showing. I use a translate animation to show the entire LinearLayout and when the network call returns on the other thread I hide the LinearLayout. Now this works great but I see that the spinner kind of stops spinning while it is showing. Now it kind of looks like if I interact with the screen, such as trying to scroll, the spinner will continue to spin. For a standard ProgressBar spinner do I need to set some command on the spinner to keep it spinning? Any information on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to detect expensive calls that are being done on the UI Thread.

Comment: That was perfect, gave me the line number of where the UI interruptions were occurring.

Comment: I've got a special use case for this: This doesn't work if you are using AsyncTask with .execute and .get. (You shouldn't do that, of course, but StrictMode won't catch the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try implementing your network call in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? In the `onPostExecute` method implementation you can do whatever is necessary on the UI (i.e hide your progressBar, etc.).

Or, if you are using the [compatibility / support library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), or targeting Honeycomb or later, use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) instead.